# Node.js uncaught exception typeError: cannot set preoprty '' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, exception

I'm trying to update an array within a model.  However The above error is thrown.  Don't know why.  The usagePlan is defined before the update is attempted.

```
customer.usagePlan.toolUsage.tools.push(aNewToolObject);
customer.updateAttribute('usagePlan',customer.usagePlan,function(err,something)    {
    //exception is thrown here
});
```

Error:

```
uncaught Exceptions: TypeError: Cannot set property 'usagePlan' of undefined
```

Docs for update attribute can be found here:

http://apidocs.strongloop.com/loopback/#persistedmodel-prototype-updateattribute

Comment: can you share the code of updateAttribute function ?

Comment: You should supply more code than this - this code can't be run as-is.  See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: So, that error makes it appear that `customer.usagePlan` is undefined.  Based on the `updateAttribute` name, it appears that maybe you should be passing the `customer` object instead of `customer.usagePlan`.

Comment: @jfriend00 if I assign the customer.usagePlan to a variable the error stays the same.

Comment: @hownowbrowncow how did you construct `customer`?  Perhaps it's not implementing PersistedModel

Comment: @Tibrogargan it is.  I was defining the contents of usagePlan on the beforeSave hook.. I changed it to the aferSave hook and now it works for some apparent reason that is huddled away behind several layers of abstraction.  I'll probs delete this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What s the code of updateAttribute ?

are you sure the second arguments is the property itself, not the object eg :

```
customer.updateAttribute('usagePlan',customer,function(err,something)
```

Comment: Yes, if I assign customer.usagePlan to a variable and add it to the function the error remains the same.

Comment: according to the exception you are trying to get the usagePlan property on a undefined object. please share the code of updateAttribute function.

Comment: That makes non sense.  usagePlan is well defined and has contents that are used throughout before this function is called.  All updateAttribute does is store changes to this attribute to DB.

Comment: Apparently I wasn't defining the 'usagePlan' property in the correct place in this framework and therefore the database couldn't recognize the object as such.  I should just delete this question?